# HTML5 Canvas: Splitting/Calculating Lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, lines

I've been banging my head on the keyboard for about one week now and I can't figure a proper solution for my problem. I think it's more Math related than HTML Canvas... hopefully someone can point me into the right direction.

I'm having an HTML Canvas where users can draw lines using they mouse and the very simple moveTo() and lineTo() functions. When the user is done I save the coords in a MongoDB. When the user hits the page later again I want to display his drawing BUT I don't want to load the entire picture with all stored coordinates at once, I want to return it in tiles (for better performance by caching each tile).

The tiles are 200x200 pixels (fixed offsets and width, starting at 0 -> 200-> 400 ->...). 
Now, when the user draws a line from let's say 50,50(x/y) to 250,250(x/y) there's only one dot in each bounding box (tile). I need to split the lines and calculate the start and ending points of each line in each bounding box (tile). Otherwise I can't draw the image partially (in tiles). It get's even more complicated when a single line crosses multiple bounding boxes (tiles). For instance: 100,100 (x/y) -> -1234,-300 (x/y).
The lines can go from any point (+/-) to ANY direction for ANY distance.

Of course I looked at Bresenham's good old algorithm and it worked - partially, but it seems like the longest and most resource-hungry solution to me.

So, the reason I'm here is that I hope someone can point me into the right direction with (perhaps) another approach of calculating the start/ending points of my lines for each bounding box.

Code examples are very welcome in JavaScript or PHP.

Thank you for reading and thinking about it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Use planes, maths explained below. There's a canvas example at the bottom.

Given that all of your cells are axis-aligned bounding boxes, you could use the plane equation to find the intersection of your line with the edges.

### Planes

You can think of your box as a set of four geometric [planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)). Each plane has a normal, or a vector of length one, indicating which direction is the "front" of the plane. The normals for the planes that make up your cell's sides would be:

```
   top = {x:  0, y: -1};
bottom = {x:  0, y:  1};
  left = {x: -1, y:  0};
 right = {x:  1, y:  0};
```

Given a point on the plane, the plane has the equation:

```
distance = (normal.x * point.x) + (normal.y * point.y)
```

You can use this equation to calculate the distance of the plane. In this case, you know the top-left corner of your box (let's say x is 10 and y is 100) is on the top plane, so you can do:

```
distance = (0 * 10) + (-1 * 100)
distance = -100
```

### Checking a point against a plane

Once you have the distance, you can reuse the equation to check where *any* point is, relative to the plane. For a random point `p` (where x is -50 and y is 90), you can do:

```
result = (normal.x * p.x) + (normal.y * p.y) - distance
result = (0 * -50) + (-1 * 90) - (-100)
result = 0 + (-90) - (-100)
result = -90 + 100
result = 10
```

There are two possible results:

```
if (result >= 0) {
    // point is in front of the plane, or coplanar.
    // zero means it is coplanar, but we don't need to distinguish.
} else {
    // point is behind the plane
}
```

### Checking a line against a plane

You can check both endpoints of a line from `a` to `b` in this way:

```
result1 = (normal.x * a.x) + (normal.y * a.y) - distance
result2 = (normal.x * b.x) + (normal.y * b.y) - distance
```

There are four possible results:

```
if (result1 >= 0 && result2 >= 0) {
  // the line is completely in front of the plane
} else if (result1 < 0 && result2 < 0) {
  // the line is completely behind the plane
} else if (result1 >= 0 && result2 < 0) {
  // a is in front, but b is behind, line is entering the plane
} else if (result1 < 0 && result2 >= 0) {
  // a is behind, but b is in front, line is exiting the plane
}
```

When the line intersects the plane, you want to find the point of intersection. It helps to think of a [line in vector terms](http://emweb.unl.edu/math/mathweb/vectors/vectors.html#vec6):

```
a + t * (b - a)
```

If `t == 0`, you are at the start of the line, and `t == 1` is the end of the line. In this context, you can calculate the point of intersection as:

```
time = result1 / (result1 - result2)
```

And the point of intersection as:

```
hit.x = a.x + (b.x - a.x) * time
hit.y = a.y + (b.y - a.y) * time
```

### Checking a line against the box

With that math, you can figure out the lines of intersection with your box. You just need to test the endpoints of your line against each plane, and find the minimum and maximum values of time.

Because your box is a [convex polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexPolygon.html), there is an early out in this check: if the line is completely **in front** of any one plane in your box, it cannot intersect with your box. You can skip checking the rest of the planes.

In JavaScript, your result might look something like this:

```
/**
 * Find the points where a line intersects a box.
 *
 * @param a Start point for the line.
 * @param b End point for the line.
 * @param tl Top left of the box.
 * @param br Bottom right of the box.
 * @return Object {nearTime, farTime, nearHit, farHit}, or false.
 */
function intersectLineBox(a, b, tl, br) {
  var nearestTime = -Infinity;
  var furthestTime = Infinity;
  var planes = [
    {nx:  0, ny: -1, dist: -tl.y},  // top
    {nx:  0, ny:  1, dist:  br.y},  // bottom
    {nx: -1, ny:  0, dist: -tl.x},  // left
    {nx:  1, ny:  0, dist:  br.x}   // right
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    var plane = planes[i];
    var nearDist = (plane.nx * a.x + plane.ny * a.y) - plane.dist;
    var farDist = (plane.nx * b.x + plane.ny * b.y) - plane.dist;
    if (nearDist >= 0 && farDist >= 0) {
      // both are in front of the plane, line doesn't hit box
      return false;
    } else if (nearDist < 0 && farDist < 0) {
      // both are behind the plane
      continue;
    } else {
      var time = nearDist / (nearDist - farDist);
      if (nearDist >= farDist) {
        // entering the plane
        if (time > nearestTime) {
          nearestTime = time;
        }
      } else {
        // exiting the plane
        if (time < furthestTime) {
          furthestTime = time;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (furthestTime < nearestTime) {
    return false;
  }
  return {
    nearTime: nearestTime,
    farTime: furthestTime,
    nearHit: {
      x: a.x + (b.x - a.x) * nearestTime,
      y: a.y + (b.y - a.y) * nearestTime
    },
    farHit: {
      x: a.x + (b.x - a.x) * furthestTime,
      y: a.y + (b.y - a.y) * furthestTime
    }
  };
}
```

If this is still too slow, you can also do [broadphase](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Broadphase) culling by dividing the world up into big rects, and assigning lines to those rects. If your line and cell aren't in the same rect, they don't collide.

**I've uploaded a [canvas example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/noonat/ZKu7s/).**

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you'd have to figure out at what point each line intersects with the bounds of each tile.

Check out the answer to this question: [Is there an easy way to detect line segment intersections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411636/is-there-an-easy-way-to-detect-line-segment-intersections)

The answers don't provide code, but it shouldn't be too hard to convert the equations to PHP or Javascript...

---

**EDIT:**

Why, exactly, do you want to split the lines?  I understand you don't want to load all the lines at once, since that could take a while.  But what's wrong with just loading and drawing the first few lines, and drawing the remainder later on?

Methinks that would be a lot simpler than having to cut up each line to fit in a specific tile.  Tiling is a nice way of optimizing bitmap loading; I don't think it's very appropriate for vector-based drawings.

You could also consider sending an Ajax request, and start drawing the whole thing whenever it comes in; this would not interfere with the loading of the page.

Comment: I'm rendering the images on serverside and return them as PNG files. This way I can cache everything pre-rendered in files on the server AND cached on the client. I don't want to use the client (browser) to re-render everything in a canvas, since it could be become huge with millions of lines.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be more expedient to draw the entire thing on-server, and then save the partial PNGs?  Or would the canvas be too large in the first place?